# Why did Manasse rule so long as recorded in 2 Kings 21?

Tags: kings, justification

2 Kings 21 (KJV)

> 1 Manasseh was twelve years old when he began to reign, and reigned fifty and five years in Jerusalem.   And his mother's name was Hephzibah.   2 And he did that which was evil in the sight of the LORD, after the abominations of the heathen, whom the LORD cast out before the children of Israel.

It seems among all the kings of Judah Manasseh ruled the longest yet he was one of the most cruel kings.

What is the reason that Manasse ruled 55 years even though he did nothing but bad against God's will?

Answer (score 1):

Part of this question is based on an incorrect assumption.  It certainly cannot be said that Manasseh did nothing but bad.  He certainly was evil and helped precipitate the events that resulted in the loss of the Hebrew monarchy and Judean capture under Nebuchadnezzar.  However, 2 Chronicles 33 records part of Manasseh's history omitted by 2 Kings.  His wickedness was so great that he was captured by Assyria.  During his captivity he repented, was released and returned as king to Jerusalem.  His reforms were welcome but too late.  His wicked son, Amnon, ascended the throne and only lasted 2 years.

The reason for the length of any given king's reign is not stated usually stated in the Bible and is unstated for Manasseh.

Comment: You quoted 2 chronicles 33 but that is the only place that say something positive about him in the OT. This is also written on Mishna - yet it seems odd that he ruled that long, while other kings that did less bad than him rulled much less.

Comment: That is true - perhaps (and this is a GUESS??) God allowed Manasseh some extra time to atone for some of his wrong-doing???  But the Bible does not say this.